# jquery load with define variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set the jQuery load target.
The below code is work.

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".first").click(function(){
var str=$(this).attr("value"); /

$(".sencond").hide();  
$("#shows").html("wait ... ");
$("#shows").show();

$("#shows").load('load.php?str='+str); 

})

})
</script>
```

I want to change the load target to 
$("#shows").load("'+str+'.php");
But this isn't work.

What 's wrong?

Comment: please try out solution `$("#shows").load( str+ ".php")`

Comment: is that worked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you do like this , there is not need of quote (`'str'`) around str.

```
$("#shows").load( str+ ".php")
```

problem with  `$("#shows").load("'+str+'.php");` it will generate string as `'strvalue'.php` and that page will not be found.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".first").click(function(){
var str=$(this).attr("value"); 

$(".sencond").hide();  
$("#shows").html("wait ... ");
$("#shows").show();

$("#shows").load(str+'.php'); 

})

})
</script>
```

make sure load php page should be there!!

Answer (score 1):

Use js template string

```
$("#shows").load(`${var}.php`)
```